# I can't seem to get the npm module 'upper-case' to work properly

Tags: node.js, npm, uppercase

I installed the npm module `upper-case` as following

```
npm install upper-case
```

Thereafter, I executed the following code in node.

```
let http = require('http');
let uc = require('upper-case');
http.createServer( (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write(uc("Hello World!"));
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

However, I can not get it to work. I get the following response.

```
TypeError: uc is not a function
    at Server.http.createServer (/.../foo.js:34:13)
    at Server.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:676:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
```

Why? What's going on!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really strange... But the following seems to work for some reason. I couldn't find this anywhere in the original npm module docs. Can anybody explain why this works?

```
let http = require('http');
let uc = require('upper-case');

http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.write(uc.upperCase("Hello World!"));
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works (i.e. drop the ".upperCase" from "uc.upperCase"):

```
var http = require('http');
var uc = require('uppercase');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
          res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
          res.write(uc("Hello World!"));
          res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: If you've read the question already, you'll know that I began with dropping the ".upperCase from uc.upperCase" as you suggested. However, the problem persisted. However, I do notice that one difference between your code and mine is that unlike myself, you are not using the fat arrow operator `=>`... So maybe that's the secret to your success.

Answer (score 0):

Do your import like this

```
import { upperCase } from "upper-case";
```

And try ?

this package exports

```
/**
 * Upper case as a function.
 */
export function upperCase(str: string) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}
```

So you can't import your own name `uc`.

Use as Described in the repo.

Comment: And then I get the following error.

`import { upperCase } from "upper-case";
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)`
...

Comment: So what's going on!?

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript 6 :  toUpperCase()

provide toUpperCase() function which id use for convert string to uppercase

so, you not need to use extra library to convert your string to uppercase

```
  res.write(("Hello World!").toUpperCase()); // try this out
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I am still interested in knowing why the original code does not work. Kindly let me know if you have any ideas.